# Smooth scrolling to an anchor on page?

Tags: jquery, scroll, anchor, smoothing

Here is the HTML for the clickable div I am using:

```
        <div class="arrow bounce" id="down-arrow" onclick="location.href='#about-me';">
```

How can I get this to scroll smoothly to the div rather than jump? I've looked at some jQuery options but they don't work as they use a href.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(".about-me").offset().top
 }, 2000);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fzctqoq7/1/

**Edit:**

```
$('#down-arrow').click(function () {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#about-me").offset().top
    }, 2000);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/eo6g642c/

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(".about-me").offset().top
     }, 2000);
   </script>
   <div class="arrow bounce" id="down-arrow" onclick="location.href='#about-me';">

This still jumps to the top of <div class="panel" id="about-me"> rather than animating.

Comment: I made the assumption that the div you're scrolling to has the class `about-me` you'll have to either add that class or change the selector

Comment: if about-me is the Id, then use `#about-me`

Comment: Should this work?

$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $("#about-me").offset().top
 }, 2000);

Comment: and remove your onclick from the div, instead add the script `$('down-arrow').click(function(){$('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $(".about-me").offset().top }, 2000); }`

Comment: you shouldn't use onclick for a div

Comment: now getting SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
    $('down-arrow').click(function(){$('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $("#about-me").offset().top }, 2000); }
   </script>
   <div class="arrow bounce" id="down-arrow">

Comment: take a look at my answer, after the Edit

Comment: Now when the arrow div is clicked nothing happens - copied the code exactly